# TweetSentiments.com API Python script

Tags: python, csv, analysis

I don’t have much experience with python but I’d like a way to store a response from TweetSentiments.com API.

For more info visit - http://intridea.com/blog/2010/11/29/sentiment-analysis-using-tweetsentimentscom-api

I have a CSV file full of different tweets and would like to be able to read from the file to the API (csvreader.fieldnames??)with a query like ‘http://data.tweetsentiments.com:8080/api/analyze.json?q=’.

It seems the only response possible is JSON but I’d prefer to return the results to another CSV file with fields like ‘tweet’ and ‘rating’.

So I am interested in creating a python script that –

Reads CSV tweet file > construct query > Interrogates API > format JSON response > writes to CSV file.

I just need a foundation as I’m struggling to find some example code.

Tried using the cURL command from the command line 
‘curl ”http://data.tweetsentiments.com:8080/api/analyze.json?q=”’

But got a ‘400 – Bad Request’ back.

I figured if I got a response back I could use this as a starting point.

Extra info – being implemented on WinXp.

Thanks in advance for the advice!

<---Update!--->

```
import csv
import urllib
import simplejson as json

Tweets=[] ## Creates empty list to store tweets.

TweetWriter = csv.writer(open('test.csv', 'w'), dialect='excel', delimiter=' ',quotechar='|')
TweetReader = csv.reader(open("C:\StoredTweets.csv", "r"))

for row in TweetReader:

    #TweetList.append(rows)
    Tweets.append({ 'tweet': row[0], 'date': row[1] }) ## Stores from CSV in list.

for rows in Tweets:

    #print TweetList
    data = urllib.urlencode({'Tweet': row[0], 'Date': row[1]}) ##Takes Tweet and date to construct query.
    #print data
    API_request = urllib.urlopen("http://data.tweetsentiments.com:8080/api/analyze.json?q=", data) ## Adds query to end of URL and queries API
    print API_request
    result = json.load(urllib.request({'API_request'}))
    print result
    TweetWriter.write(result) ## Writes API Response to CSV file.
```

It’s the json.load part I can’t seem to get the hang of. I’ve looked at loads of different examples and can’t seem to understand it. The API_request should hold my json structure I think?  Should the json reponse be stored in another list? I keep getting told “AttributeError: ‘module’ object had no attribute ‘request’.  Thanks for taken the time to go over this with me!

```
C:\>python TweetSentiment.py
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
  body { text-align:center;font-family:helvetica,arial;font-size:22px;
    color:#888;margin:20px}
  #c {margin:0 auto;width:500px;text-align:left}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h2>Sinatra doesn't know this ditty.</h2>
  <img src='/__sinatra__/404.png'>
  <div id="c">
    Try this:
    <pre>post '/api/analyze' do
  "Hello World"
end</pre>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sort of thing Python is great for -- good choice! There are a few different things you need to do, in order.

- Read the CSV file.

  You will want to use the `csv` module; specifically, `csv.Reader` or `csv.DictReader` (depending on whether you want tuples or dictionaries of each row.
- Construct the query.

  Have a look at [`urllib.urlencode`](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlencode) (in Python2 -- the name has changed slightly in Python 3, to [`urllib.parse.quote`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.2.2/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote)).
- Interrogate API.

  `urllib.request`. Plenty of documentation for this! You may need to do some HTTPS stuff, include an API key, that sort of thing.
- Format JSON response.

  [`json.load`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#json.load) will return you a dictionary from the `urllib.Request` object.
- Write CSV.

  `csv.writer`.

Is there any particular step in here you'd like help with?

---

Here's a *very* quick idea of what the code might end up looking like.

```
with open(...) as inputs, open(..., "w") as outputs:
    inputs = csv.reader(inputs)
    outputs = csv.writer(outputs)

    for line in inputs:
        query = urllib.urlencode(...)
        result = json.load(urllib.request(...))
        outputs.write(result["spam"], result["ham"])
```

Comment: No thanks, this is exactly what I’m looking for, you’ve given me everything I need to get started!
The example code is excellent too! 
Thanks for your prompt reply and sorry about the time taken to reply.
Cheer.

Comment: I'm struggling with the json.load part of the script. If i edited the question above could you maybe give me some advice?

Comment: Sure =) If you do `urllib.request.urlopen(...).read()` (or the corresponding function for your version of Python) do you get all the data you expect?

Comment: I've updated the question above so you can see what I've done.

Comment: Ah, I see what you've done. `urlopen` does the request, so you don't need to call `urllib.request` (which is a module in any case). `urlopen` will return a file-like object, which you've called `API_request`. What happens if you call `print API_request.read()`?

Comment: I put the response above so it’s easier to read. It doesn’t look like it has my json response in it which must mean I’ve done something wrong?

Comment: Is what you put above the result of doing `API_request.read()`? If so you've got the API call wrong. You can check this in a normal browser by `print`ing the URL you think you're accessing.

Comment: I’ve just tried the exact same request in a browser and it worked! It was this - "http://data.tweetsentiments.com:8080/api/analyze.json?q=Date=+u%27created_at%27%3A+u%27Thu+Nov+03+15%3A39%3A04+%2B0000+2011%27&Tweet=%7C%7Bu%27text%27%3A+u%27HRT+extends+technical+deal+with+Williams%3A+%23F1+-+The+HRT+team+has+announced+it+has+extended+it+technical+deal+wit...+http%3A%2F%2Ft.co%2F7qCXx3K0%27"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8685/discussion-between-katrielalex-and-chris-chalmers)